# Wordpress pagination is returning inconsistent number of posts per page

Tags: php, sql, wordpress, pagination

By using wordpress wp_query with pagination with this settings:

```
$args = array (
  'paged' => $paged,
  'posts_per_page' => 50,
  'ignore_sticky_posts'=>true,
  'post_type'   => 'place',
  'meta_query'  => array(
  'relation'    => 'AND',
   $query
));
```

The SQL on page 1 that I am getting is:

```
string(997) "SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS wp_posts.ID FROM wp_posts
...
...
...
ORDER BY wp_posts.post_date DESC LIMIT 0, 50" string(4) "1472"
```

But why the number of posts displayed on this page is only 48 instead of 50? Different pages display different posts per page, e.g. 14, 27.. etc. Can somebody please help me understand what is going on?

Comment: add `'post_status'=> 'publish'` parametar